# Check if UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl exists in iOS version

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, typedef, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to check if `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` exists on a given device.

*Note: `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` exists on iOS 4.0 and above. I am also targeting iOS 3.1.3. Don't worry about the targeting iOS 3 part.*

Currently tried: 
`if (UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl != NULL)`

and

`if ((UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl) == TRUE)`

to check existence of the constant (Is `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` considered a constant? It's a value of `typedef enum` `UIBarButtonSystemIcon`). These two methods are currently not working. Can someone provide guidance on checking the existence a value of in a struct (not the containing struct)? Thanks.

Comment: Does `if (&UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl != NULL)` work?

Comment: No, it does not work. LLVM compile error: _Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator_

What difference does a `&` (ampersand) in front of the it make?

Comment: Makes sense. What I suggested is how to check for (extern) constants. It was a shot in the dark that it might work with enum values. To be honest, I don't think there is a runtime check for enum values. You might need to check `UIDevice systemVersion` and see if it starts with `@"3"`. I always hate such checks but it may be the only choice here.

Comment: I just tried to do a bitwise, check too.
`if((UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl & 23) == 23)`
On iOS 3, the bitwise check returns 23 so does this mean the `UIBarButtonSystemImemPageCurl` exists in the struct but just isn't implemented? I'm thinking that there is a way to compare "implementations" by comparing the result of `initWithBarButtonSystemItem`.

Comment: Probably better to check the version of iOS.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in UIBarButtonItem.h, you'll find that `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` is defined conditionally using the preprocessor:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIBarButtonSystemItem) {
    ⋮
#if __IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl,
#endif
};
```

`…_MAX_ALLOWED` is defined to the SDK version. Once the constant is defined, the constant always exists.

Comparing it against `NULL` is meaningless because this isn't a pointer. You are effectively comparing it against zero, and as it isn't the first thing in the enumeration, it isn't zero, so it is never `NULL`.

What it *is* is an integer. `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` is synonymous with `23`, and the number `23` always exists, regardless of OS version.

So the question becomes “is `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` (a.k.a. `23`) something that UIKit will recognize?”

One way to find that out would be to pass it to `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:` and see what happens. Hopefully, it will either return `nil` or throw an exception; either way, you can detect that and recover by doing whatever you need to do on iOS 3 devices.

Another way would be to [ask the device for its `systemVersion`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion) and compare it to `@"4.0"` in a way that understands version numbers. The Growl project has [code for parsing and comparing version number strings](http://code.google.com/p/growl/source/browse/Common/Source/GrowlVersionUtilities.m). It's written for OS X, but should work with little to no modification on iOS.

I'd do the try-it-and-see approach first. Only if it silently fails (i.e., always returns a UIBarButtonItem, even on iOS 3, and the item you get on 3 just doesn't work) should you resort to comparing OS versions.

Comment: To elaborate: `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` is an enumeration value. That means it exists at compile-time, not run-time, and so has no address in memory. In this situation (enum values that may or may not exist), you must check the OS version explicitly, or check for a selector or symbol that only exists as of the OS version that added the enum value.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: Or try to use the constant and recover if it fails.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that approach. Bad inputs may cause exceptions to be thrown or assertions to fail rather than a recoverable error code to be returned. Consider what happens if you pass `NSUIntegerMax` to `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]` on an empty array.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: Exceptions can be caught.

Comment: Exceptions from Apple are meant to be fatal. If an exception is thrown from an Apple framework, the application enters an undefined state. From the documentation: "The general pattern is that exceptions are reserved for programmer error only, and the program catching such an exception should quit soon afterwards."

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: Fair enough.